# C Variable changes after initializing other variables

Tags: c, struct, malloc, sizeof

I am writing a command-line todo list program in C and am getting some weird behavior. Todos are stored in structs which contain an `int` priority and a `char[128]` name. They are created using a function that takes in these parameters and returns an allocated and initialized struct with those values.

The returned structs are initially correct, but after initializing 8 more struct variables, the value of the first-initialized structs begins to change. My guess is that previous values are being overwritten by new ones due to not enough memory being allocated. I've fixed this problem temporarily by increasing the size fed to `malloc()` from `sizeof(TaskP)` to `sizeof(int) + sizeof(char[128])`. However, I am sure there is a better way and would much appreciate an explanation of why `malloc(sizeof(TaskP)` is not allocating enough memory (if that is the case) and the proper convention.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Task {
    char description[128];              /* description of the task */
    int priority;                       /* task priority */
};

typedef  struct Task* Task;


Task createTask (int priority, char *desc)
{
  Task newTask = malloc(sizeof(Task));
  if (newTask) {
    newTask->priority = priority;
    strcpy(newTask->description, desc);
  }
  return newTask;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Task taskList[10];

    Task task1 = createTask(9, "task 1");
    printf("task1: %d\n", task1->priority);  /* I put printfs */
    Task task2 = createTask(3, "task 2");
    printf("task1: %d\n", task1->priority);  /* after every call */
    Task task3 = createTask(2, "task 3");
    printf("task1: %d\n", task1->priority);  /* to createTask() */
    Task task4 = createTask(4, "task 4");
    printf("task1: %d\n", task1->priority);  /* to watch the value */
    Task task5 = createTask(5, "task 5");
    printf("task1: %d\n", task1->priority);  /* of task1 change */
    Task task6 = createTask(7, "task 6");
    printf("task1: %d\n", task1->priority);
    Task task7 = createTask(8, "task 7");
    printf("task1: %d\n", task1->priority);
    Task task8 = createTask(6, "task 8");
    printf("task1: %d\n", task1->priority);
    Task task9 = createTask(1, "task 9");
    printf("task1: %d\n", task1->priority);
    Task task10 = createTask(0, "task 10");
    printf("task1: %d\n", task1->priority);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is my output:

```
task1: 9
task1: 9
task1: 9
task1: 9
task1: 9
task1: 9
task1: 9
task1: 0
task1: 1802723700
task1: 1802723700
```

### **UPDATE**

I literally figured out the problem seconds after posting to stack overflow. How embarrassing. The problem is that I was only allocating enough memory for a pointer (`Task`), which has a size of 8 bytes, instead of memory for `struct Task`, which has a size of 132 bytes. Thank you to everyone who patiently answered and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Just a note, `typedef  struct Task* Task;` is confusing, especially when you have a `struct Task`. Please don't `typedef` pointers.

Comment: I usually would not, but that is pre-written code from my computer science professor that I can't change. Thank you though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem.

```
Task newTask = malloc(sizeof(Task));
```

You are allocating enough memory to hold only a pointer, not a `struct Task`.

Change it to:

```
Task newTask = malloc(sizeof(*newTask));
```

FWIW, having `Task` as a `typedef` for `struct Task*` is not a good idea. It will be better to use:

```
typedef struct Task Task;
typedef struct Task* TaskPtr;
```

and then use

```
Task* newTaskPtr = malloc(sizeof(Task));
```

or

```
TaskPtr newTaskPtr = malloc(sizeof(Task));
```

Comment: I have been puzzled by this for three days, have shown it to my professor and several grad students, none of whom knew what was wrong, and I literally just came up with this same solution seconds after posting. How embarrassing. Thank you sir.

Comment: @rfarry, you are welcome. No need to feel embarrassed. Most of us have committed similar errors.

Comment: There's a reason why seasoned C programmers live by the rule **Don't bother with typedefs for structs!** All it saves you is occasionally writing `struct`--an information you usually don't want to hide.

Comment: It's a shame that professors didn't recognize the error immediately, though. The type of the variable you assign the return value of `malloc()` is **always** different from the type you get the size of (it is a pointer to that type).